# procmail recipe assistance

Tags: procmail

I know just enough about regexp to make my brain hurt and I was hoping for some assistance.

I need a recipe to take any mail that doesn't have the string "ZYX" in the TO: line and dump it into "0.waste".  Would someone be willing to lend a hand?

Answer (score 2):

There is no real need for nontrivial regex here. Just add `!` in front of the condition to say "if not this then".

```
:0:
* ! ^To:.*ZYX
0.waste
```

If `0.waste` is not an mbox file, (i.e. does not need locking), take out the second colon in `:0:`

There is also the `^TO_` macro but it examines a lot more than just the `To:` header, and is anchored specifically to look for delimited addresses (so an address which starts with `ZYX`, not a line with this substring anywhere in it).